# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() PHP CLASS

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm trying to write this class to connect and query my database, but I got this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in
>   C:\xxxxxx\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxxx\pages\config\class.php on line 24

Php Code:

```
<?php

class Db{

    private static $db_host = "localhost";
    private static $db_user = "root";
    private static $db_pass = "";
    private static $db_name = "sivi";

    public $connection;

        public function db_connect() {    

            $connection = mysqli_connect(self::$db_host, self::$db_user, self::$db_pass, self::$db_name) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection)); 
            echo "Conexión realizada". "<br>";

    }  

    public function db_query($query){

          $connection = $this->db_connect();
          var_dump($query);
          $result = $connection->query($query);
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
          echo $row["COD_PRE"] . "<br>";
          }

    } 

}

$con = new Db();
$con->db_query('SELECT `COD_PRE`, `CODE` FROM `test` WHERE `CODE` = 457 AND CONFIN = 1');

?>
```

Comment: Try changing `$connection->query($query);` to `$this->connection->query($query);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method:

```
public function db_connect() {    

            $connection = mysqli_connect(self::$db_host, self::$db_user, self::$db_pass, self::$db_name) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection)); 
            echo "Conexión realizada". "<br>";

    }
```

does not retun the `$connection` back from the method so the rest method calls fail do this:

```
public function db_connect() {    

            $connection = mysqli_connect(self::$db_host, self::$db_user, self::$db_pass, self::$db_name) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection)); 
            echo "Conexión realizada". "<br>";
           return $connection; // return the $connection object
    }
```

As mentioned, your code is not efficient since for every query performed the code (re-)connects to the DB. THis is unnecessarily expensive/inefficient.

There are many approaches to solve this.

1. Connect to the DB on the instantiation of the DB class

e.g

```
class Db{

    private static $db_host = "localhost";
    private static $db_user = "root";
    private static $db_pass = "";
    private static $db_name = "sivi";

    public $connection;

    public function __construct()
   {
      $this->connection = $this->db_connect();
   }  

    public function db_connect() {    

            $connection = mysqli_connect(self::$db_host, self::$db_user, self::$db_pass, self::$db_name) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection)); 
            echo "Conexión realizada". "<br>";
            return $connection;
    }  
}
```

2. Lazy connection, i.e connect only on first executed query

e.g

```
class Db{

    private static $db_host = "localhost";
    private static $db_user = "root";
    private static $db_pass = "";
    private static $db_name = "sivi";
    public $connection = null;
    public function __construct()
    {
    }  
    public function db_connect() {    
        $connection = mysqli_connect(self::$db_host, self::$db_user, self::$db_pass, self::$db_name) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection)); 
        echo "Conexión realizada". "<br>";
        return $connection;
    }  
    public function db_query($query){
        if ( null ==== $this->connection ) $this->connection = $this->db_connect();
        var_dump($query);
        $result = $this->connection->query($query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
            echo $row["COD_PRE"] . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, for every query you want to create a new connection to `mysql`? That will kill performance.

Comment: @Achrome, true did not comment on code erfficiency, just on the bug, updating answer

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `$this` to access properties of the own class.

```
$this->connection = ....

$result = $this->connection->...
```

It would be better if you used a constructor to initiate the connection, currently you are opening a new connection to the database every time you use the query method.

edit: Your class could look like this

```
<?php

class Db {

    private $db_host = "localhost";
    private $db_user = "root";
    private $db_pass = "";
    private $db_name = "sivi";
    private $connection;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->db_name) 
                or die("Error " . mysqli_error($this->connection));
    }

    public function db_query($query) {
        var_dump($query);
        $result = $this->connection->query($query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo $row["COD_PRE"] . "<br>";
        }
    }

}

$con = new Db();
$con->db_query('SELECT `COD_PRE`, `CODE` FROM `test` WHERE `CODE` = 457 AND CONFIN = 1');
?>
```

I see no need for the properties to be static, so I changed them too.

The db_query method is in my opinion too unflexible, as it directly outputs your result. I would use fetch_all to return the whole resultset as an array.
That way you can freely choose how you want to handle your results.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to OP (and others) if you could update your answer to add code for the constructor approach that you mentioned in addition to what you already have there.